# Joomla and DOMPDF integration errors

Tags: joomla, dompdf

I'm trying to integrate DOMPDF to our Joomla (Version 1.5.24) project and I keep getting these errors:

```
    Strict standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\libraries\loader.php on line 162
    Strict standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\libraries\loader.php on line 139
    Fatal error: Class 'DOMPDF' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\components\com_reports\views\details\view.pdf.php on line 23
    Strict standards: Non-static method JFactory::getDBO() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\oasis\libraries\joomla\session\storage\database.php on line 84
    Strict standards: Non-static method JTable::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\oasis\libraries\joomla\session\storage\database.php on line 89
    Strict standards: Non-static method JFactory::getDBO() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\oasis\libraries\joomla\database\table.php on line 112
```

The function that instantiates the DOMPDF object is located in one of the views of the component:

```
class ReportsViewDetails extends JView{
  function display($tpl = null){
    global $mainframe;
    //echo "hello";
    $this->generatePDF();
   }

  function generatePDF(){
    require_once("./components/com_reports/helper/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $html =
      '<html><body>'.
      '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
      'templating system.</p>'.
      '</body></html>';

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
   }
}
```

It sees the file that is required but dompdf_config.inc.php outputs errors described above. I'm not sure what is causing this since the file only contains `define` lines and an `autoload` function. The content of the file can be seen here: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/browse/trunk/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: if you guys have any suggestion on HTML-PDF tools that are easier to use, then please be my guest and post it as well. So far I have tried HTML2FPDF with FPDF and it does not meet my requirements (need to show a header for each generated page but somehow the html result generated does not automatically position itself after the header for the 2nd page and below. if you know how to fix this, please also share :D )

Comment: the error says it all it cannot find DOMPDF class and why are you including path to a config file? shouldnt the path be for the file that actually implements this class?

Comment: according to what I understand in the config file, it `includes` the file that implements the DOMPDF class. I think that's how they implemented it.

Comment: Which version of dompdf? You link to the latest version of dompdf_config.inc.php in the code repository, but if you're using 0.5.1 it uses a different autoloader that may not be compatible with Joomla. 0.6.0 includes more up-to-date autoloader code.

Comment: I tried dompdf_0-6-0_beta2 and it now produces a PDF, however it is corrupt. Upon looking at the contents of the file, the ff. error is seen: 

`Fatal error: Class 'JResponse' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\oasis\libraries\joomla\document\document.php on line 776`

Comment: JResponse isn't a dompdf class. Either something is not implemented correctly or the dompdf autoloader in 0.6.0 is still conflicting with Joomla. If you remove the dompdf code and just echo the $html variable does the page work correctly?

Comment: When I removed the `require_once` line, `$html` can be echoed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

all those strict standard warnings you are getting is becuase of this line

error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);

in dompdf_config.inc.php

and you should include dompdf/include/dompdf.cls.php

Comment: Actually, as dompdf is currently designed you should include dompdf_config.inc.php. This file sets constants that DOMPDF requires and defines an autoloader that loads the necessary class files during rendering.